# Reading Data from a file Bottle Py server

Tags: javascript, python, html, d3.js, bottle

I am trying to make a HTML file work on a bottlepy server. This is my code for the bottlepy server :

import bottle
from bottle import route, run, template, static_file

```
@route('/plot')
def plot():
    return static_file('histogram.html', root='./')

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

The basic html works fine. But I need to read data from a csv file in the same location as the html file. I am using D3.csv for this. While it worked fine in a Netbeans project, this isn't working in this format. Where am  I going wrong? Suppose my data file is called "data.csv", and I call this function -

```
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data){ ... }
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT : By this isn't working, I meant the JavaScript doesn't read any data. I am not sure if a local file can be accessed by a HTML file. Netbeans probably identifies the files needed and deploys the site appropriately.

Comment: What exactly is the error you're seeing?  ("this isn't working" is quite vague.)

Comment: There isn't an error, the script is not able to access the data/file.

Comment: Yes, but what does "not able" mean?  What happens when you try?

Comment: Nothing happens. The part of the site where the data is supposed to be displayed is blank.